# Safari tabbing focus doesn't work in 5.1.2

Tags: safari, focus

When I keep pressing tab key, it only focuses through the form elements (like `input`, `button`) but not through anchor tags.

It was working fine in ver 5.0.5. This behavior is noticed in latest version 5.1.2.

Comment: Yep I've been testing some stuff recently under Safari 5.1.5 (WinXP) recently and when you have elements with tabindex="0", all the elements EXCEPT links (<a> with "href" defined) are focusable. By all elements, I mean <span>s, <div>s etc. It's absolutely amazing for me from the accessibility point of view!

Answer (score 23):

If you go under the advanced preferences in Safari and check "Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage" it works.

Comment: Thank you, it works... 
But isn't that an accessibility issue not allowing users to access links through keyboard automatically without updating the settings :?
Not sure whats the idea of safari behind this behaviour.

Comment: Why isn't this option be enabled by default?

Comment: Bump, 4 years later and still it isn't enabled by default, what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: I can't believe this is not enabled by default. One more facepalm for Safari

Comment: @JosephK.: I believe the reason is so it matches the way the MacOS works by default across all applications.  You can also press Option + Tab to include links while tabbing.  I don't find it intuitive either, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways for a user to fix this.

**1.** The main fix for this is to adjust the Accessibility options. Apple Menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts Tab > **Full keyboard access: In windows and dialogs, press Tab to move the keyboard focus between:** Choose the "**All controls**" radio button. This allows Safari, as well as other applications, to gain tab focus on buttons and other UI elements.

[image: Full Keyboard Access]

**2.** Additionally, you can adjust this in Safari's advanced preferences as noted in [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691)'s answer.