# Safari anchor tags with href attribute not getting focus?

Tags: html, css, safari, focus, accessibility

I came across this issue and I thought my code was just wrong, but after searching around and looking at related examples, I wonder if Safari really doesn't focus `<a>` tags with `href` attribute?

In my use case, I wanted to use `<a href="#top">jump</a>` to skip to a page section. To make the anchor tag focusable, we need to add `tabindex="0"` like so -> `<a href="#top" tabindex="0">jump</a>`. However, it seems the presence of `href` attribute is not OK with Safari. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8426rLe/2/) and try to Tab through the page (modified from other SO example).

HTML

```
<a tabindex="0">Test 1</a>
<a href="#" tabindex="0">Test 2</a>
```

CSS

```
a:focus { color: orange; }
```

Is there any way to fix this? Same code works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747689/safari-tabbing-focus-doesnt-work-in-5-1-2

Comment: http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2014/07/07/keyboard-navigation-in-mac-browsers/

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, thank you for the links, I can confirm the behaviour is now the same as in Chrome, but I cannot expect my users to do this themselves. What would you suggest should the ideal solution be?

Comment: @lmenus Wouldn't you expect Safari users to be able to decide for themselves if they want to enable this feature or not?

Comment: @MrLister What are the downsides to having this feature enabled?

Comment: Having the feature enabled means you have more tab stops in safari.  That could annoy a keyboard user, but if it's not enabled, how would a keyboard user get to the link to select it?  I found this feature of safari pretty bizarre.  It's the first thing I turn on when I get a new mac.  And, yes, you will have to teach your users how to turn this on.

Comment: @slugolicious Thank you, definitely a frustrating UX. I wonder how this affects a11y users as that's the primary concern of the feature where I noticed this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this behavior is by design, and as such there's not much that you as a web-developer can do about it. Ultimately, it's up to the end-user whether or not they want to enable these settings.

I can tell you that Safari is used regularly by screen reader users, particularly on iOS. You can see evidence of this in the latest [WebAIM Screen Reader User Survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey7/#browsers). These people seem to navigate the technology without issue, so I suspect that it's not really a problem.

Technologies frequently change, so the best thing that you can do is to code to the specification and provide graceful fallbacks for poor accessibility support where you can. Unfortunately, I don't see any way of doing that in this case.

I would not recommend trying to implement workarounds (via scripting), as this will likely only cause more problems.